# Change caption and attributes of ShowMessage dialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

In Delphi can you change the caption of the `ShowMessage` dialog because by default it is taking my exe name.

And can I change the background color, size of the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create your own custom dialogs by using delphi's `CreateMessageDialog` function.

Example below:

```
var
  Dlg: TForm;
begin
  Dlg := CreateMessageDialog('message', mtInformation, [mbOk], mbOK);
  // Treat Dlg like any other form

  Dlg.Caption := 'Hello World';

  try
    // The message label is named 'message'
    with TLabel(Dlg.FindComponent('message')) do
    begin
      Font.Style := [fsUnderline];

      // extraordinary code goes here
    end;

    // The icon is named... icon
    with TPicture(Dlg.FindComponent('icon')) do
    begin
      // more amazing code regarding the icon
    end;

    Dlg.ShowModal;
  finally
    Dlg.Free;
  end;
```

and of course you can insert other components aswell into that form dynamically.

Comment: I never knew `FindComponent` existed.  +1!

Answer (score 8):

The dialog will use the contents of `Application.Title` as the caption. So you could set this before calling `ShowMessage`.

However, if you want to show multiple dialogs with different captions, it would be more convenient to call the Windows [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. Certainly if you have an older version of Delphi this will result in a more native feel to your dialog.

```
procedure MyShowMessage(const Msg, Caption: string);
begin
  MessageBox(GetParentWindowHandleForDialog, PChar(Msg), PChar(Caption), MB_OK);
end;

function GetParentWindowHandleForDialog: HWND;
begin
  //we must be careful that the handle we use here doesn't get closed while the dialog is showing
  if Assigned(Screen.ActiveCustomForm) then begin
    Result := Screen.ActiveCustomForm.Handle;
  end else if Assigned(Application.MainForm) then begin
    Result := Application.MainFormHandle;
  end else begin
    Result := Application.Handle;
  end;
end;
```

If you wish to control color and size then the most obvious option is to create your own dialog as a `TForm` descendent.

Comment: i cant find `MianWindowHandle` in  BDS 2006
having a custom form as a dialog box seem to be an option

Comment: I misremembered. It's MainFormHandle in Delphi. I'm answering too many WinForms questions!!!

Comment: but it violates the `Showmodal` property of `Showmessages`

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand that comment.

Comment: when u display a MessageDialog box using a `Showmessage` the control of the aplication goes to the Showmessage Dialog
but in this case the control is still with the application when the `MessageBox` is called

Comment: Windows `MessageBox` is modal also. A TForm descdendant can be modal by showing it with `ShowModal`. Both options I present can operator modally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4232/discussion-between-shirish11-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code I wrote, you might want to use it note for note.

```
function SetHook(Code : Integer; wparam : Integer; LParam : Integer) : Longint;    stdcall;
function HookWndProc(wnd : HWND ;uMsg : UINT;  wParam : WPARAM; lParam : LPARAM ) :   LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  CaptHook : HHOOK;
  GHookProc : TFNWndProc;
  GOldHookProc : TFNWndProc;
implementation

uses Messages, Types, Graphics;

  function SetHook(Code : Integer; wparam : Integer; LParam : Integer) : Longint; stdcall;
 var
   pwp : CWPSTRUCT;
 begin
 if Code = HC_ACTION then
 begin
   pwp := CWPStruct(Pointer(LParam)^);
   if pwp.message = WM_INITDIALOG then
   begin
     GOldHookProc := TFnWndProc(SetWindowLong(pwp.hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, LongInt(GHookProc)));
   end;
  end;

 result := CallNextHookEx(CaptHook, Code, wparam, lparam);

end;

function HookWndProc(wnd : HWND ;uMsg : UINT;  wParam : WPARAM; lParam : LPARAM ) : LRESULT;
var
  DC : HDC;
  WndRect : Trect;
  BR: HBRUSH;
  WndText : array[1..20] of  char;
begin

 result := CallWindowProc(GOldHookProc, wnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
 if uMsg = WM_ERASEBKGND then
 begin
    GetWindowText(wnd, @wndText, 20);

    //do stuff here (I colored the button red)
    DC := GetDC(wnd);
    WndRect := Rect(0, 0, 200,200);
    BR := CreateSolidBrush(clRed);
    FillRect(dc, WndRect, BR);
    DeleteObject(BR);
    ReleaseDC(wnd, dc);
 end;
end;
```

...

Put this in your Form Create where you want to make the funky message boxes

```
uses windows;
```

...

```
 CaptHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @SetHook, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);
 GHookProc := @HookWndProc;
```

So, what this does is hook into Windows' dialog popup functions and you can get the context for the dialog and draw on it.

Comment: @David I had to write this for an internal app because some of the tech guys here wanted to have red buttons on important warning messages.  It's essentially a hook that can draw on the 'canvas' of the dialog you pop up.  You can draw in the place where the comments are.